# Is it possible to link to an array file in add_theme_support( 'editor-color-palette' );

Tags: wordpress, plugins, wordpress-gutenberg

I'm building a simple color palette plugin that's going to override the gutenburg color settings.

Normally, you can add colors in `add_theme_support( 'editor-color-palette' );` in an array like this:

```
add_theme_support(
    'editor-color-palette',
    [
      [
        'name'  => esc_html__( 'Brown', 'udemy-plugin' ),
        'slug'  => 'brown',
        'color' => '#3a3335',
      ],
      [
        'name'  => esc_html__( 'Orange', 'udemy-plugin' ),
        'slug'  => 'orange',
        'color' => '#f0544f',
      ],
      [
        'name'  => esc_html__( 'Light Green', 'udemy-plugin' ),
        'slug'  => 'light-green',
        'color' => '#c6d8d3',
      ],

    ]
  );
```

However, I was wondering if it's possible to link the array part to a file? like this:

```
add_theme_support( 'editor-color-palette', $link-to-array );
```

If it's possible, how do I link the array file in the plugin? So far, my plugin folder is set up like this:

```
-Plugin Folder
   -plugin.php (where my code is in)
```

Answer (score 1):

In WordPress 5.8, [theme.json](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/how-to-guides/themes/theme-json/) was introduced as a way to better manage custom CSS styles for Gutenberg blocks as an alternative to `add_theme_support()`. Given your example code, to define and apply a custom colors for a Gutenberg block in the Editor, [custom properties and presets in theme.json](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/how-to-guides/themes/theme-json/#css-custom-properties-presets-custom) would be perfect for this.

Eg. json: **modified** *only colors are required for 'editor-color-palette'*

```
[
    {
        "name": "Brown",
        "slug": "brown",
        "color": "#3a3335"
    },
    {
        "name": "Orange",
        "slug": "orange",
        "color": "#f0544f"
    },
    {
         "name": "Light Green",
         "slug": "light-green",
         "color": "#ffffff"
    }
]
```

The WordPress documentation also has a how-to guide on creating a block-based theme which may help:
https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/how-to-guides/themes/create-block-theme/

As WordPress and Gutenberg blocks are still be actively developed/updated, always check the official documentation for the latest syntax and up-to-date examples.

**UPDATE**
Here is how to load and decode the theme.json

```
function wpdc_gutenberg_color_settings() {
...
    $dir = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ );

    $theme_colors = json_decode(
        file_get_contents( $dir . "theme.json" ), // Returns contents of file as string
        true // Decodes the JSON string into an associative array
    );
add_theme_support('editor-color-palette', $theme_colors );
}
```

Comment: Sorry for taking a while to get back.  I'm trying to build a plugin. Is block-based theme the same as the plugin I'm building? And what about older wordpress versions such as 5.7 or earlier? Can I link theme.json to plugin.php too? I am still confused.

Comment: @KristinaBressler Both `add_theme_support()` and `theme.json` let you set the editor color palette, with theme.json being the newer way. In your example code, the array could be in another file, as long the file is included in plugin.php file. I recommend moving towards theme.json if your plugin is just setting editor color palette, there is backwards compatibility (https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/how-to-guides/themes/theme-json/#backward-compatibility-with-add_theme_support)  for `add_theme_support()`.

Comment: Ok, when I'm done, can I send you a link for you to review if you have time? Or is there a Slack channel I can ask as well for reviewing of my simple basic plugin?

Comment: If it is just setting editor color palettes and solves your question, you could add the relevant code/link to github as the answer to your question. One other potential issue you might come across is themes generally set/control this, so if it doesn't work at first, look in the themes functions.php and see if anything is overriding your plugin.

Comment: I already fixed that sort of few weeks ago by adding `100` in add_action in plugin.php. It makes this function in my plugin.php the highest priority than the theme's functions.php. Though I don't know if I can do the same for theme.json. Anyway, here's my link: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/building-my-1st-plugin-theme-json/. I think I am having problems in connecting stuff together as I was trying out different solutions.

Comment: @KristinaBressler I had a look at your sample plugin and I've added example of loading and decoding in my answer above for the theme.json however, the more I played around with this, the more I lean towards it would be easier to create a child theme and simply have the theme.json, editor-styles.scss/css and load them via add_editor_style() in functions.php which would automatically find the json and editor styles, interested to see which way you go..

Comment: I'm so close to be done. I use your advice/code to edit my plugin and it's working on back-end. However, I still need to edit the style.css so that it'll display on front-end. How do I import the theme.json in style.css? Is it `@import 'theme.json'`? Also I changed the style.css to scss because I found this article that could help. https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/378402/wp-gutenberg-custom-block-generate-theme-colors-from-sass-and-use-them-in-the